# What's the practical difference between the Command Window and the Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Just curious.

Comment: immediate window is a debugging tool, command window is like the windows command prompt, but for visual studio

Comment: Related posts - [Visual Studio Command Window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557371/465053) & [Command vs. Immediate Window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9000665/465053)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This [blog post](http://dotnetdud.wordpress.com/2007/12/25/immediate-and-command-window-in-visual-studio/) offers a pretty decent overview of the users of the two windows. Quote from that page:

> The **Command window** is used to execute
>   commands or aliases directly in the
>   Visual Studio integrated development
>   environment (IDE). You can execute
>   both menu commands and commands that
>   do not appear on any menu. To display
>   the Command window, choose Other
>   Windows from the View menu, and select
>   Command Window
>
> The **Immediate window** is used to debug
>   and evaluate expressions, execute
>   statements, print variable values, and
>   so forth. It allows you to enter
>   expressions to be evaluated or
>   executed by the development language
>   during debugging. To display the
>   Immediate window, open a project for
>   editing, then choose Windows from the
>   Debug menu and select Immediate.

It also includes a seemingly very complete list of commands and aliases that you can execute (for VS 2005 at least) - from either window, as far as I understand. Once of the nice features is that you can switch between the two windows simply by executing the `cmd` and `immed` commands.

In addition, see also the MSDN pages on the [Command Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) and the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

One difference between the two is that the Command Window will accept commands at any time (Visual Studio Commands) whereas the Immediate Window (Evaluations) only accepts commands during a debugging session.

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN (Command Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz(VS.80).aspx):

> The Command window is used to execute
>   commands or aliases directly in the
>   Visual Studio integrated development
>   environment (IDE). You can execute
>   both menu commands and commands that
>   do not appear on any menu.

From [MSDN (Immediate Window)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(VS.80).aspx):

> The Immediate window is used at design
>   time to debug and evaluate
>   expressions, execute statements, print
>   variable values, and so forth. It
>   allows you to enter expressions to be
>   evaluated or executed by the
>   development language during debugging.