# Visual Studio Command Window

Tags: visual-studio

What is the usefulness of the Command Window in Visual Studio (menu *View* -> *Other Windows* -> *Command Window*)?

I know that the Visual Studio [Command Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) is used to execute commands or aliases directly in the IDE. The MSDN article *[Command Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx)* explains how one can use the command window to print debug statements, but I feel that these can be easier executed in the Immediate Window.

What is the Command Window for?

Comment: Related post - [Command vs. Immediate Window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9000665/465053)

Comment: Also, if someone wants to run trivial windows shell commands while staying within Visual Studio - [Using the command line from within Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9827567/465053)

Comment: Related post - [What's the practical difference between the Command Window and the Immediate Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/913316/465053)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Immediate window is mostly used for debugging, variable evaluation, etc. You sound familiar with it, so I won't belabor its usage. For more information on it, check out the MSDN article *[Immediate Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy(v=vs.140).aspx)*.

The Command window allows you to execute a variety of commands using their aliases. You'll notice that the command window prompt has a `>` character. You can open a file in your solution using `of Class1.cs`, hit enter, and open it up. In the Find dialog and Immediate window you would need to include the >, making it `>of Class1.cs`.

Nonetheless, you can do exactly the same thing in the Immediate window by prefixing a command with `>` as well. The Command window saves you an extra keystroke and is ready to go whenever you drop a command alias.

Check out these links for some commands:

- [Predefined Visual Studio Command Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3a0kd3x.aspx)
- [Immediate Window Commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171362.aspx)

For example, to open the Quick Watch window, type `??` in the command window. Try that in the Immediate window and you'll get:

```
??
Invalid expression term '?'
```

Type `>??` in the Immediate window, and it'll work.

Comment: also note that (at least in VS 2010) you get intellisense. Type o and pause, and of will be offered to you. Take it (arrows and tab) and type the first letter of a file, and you'll be offered files to choose from. That can make it a lot faster than scrolling around in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

The Command Window offers a command-prompt style interaction with the IDE which some people seem to like, but all of the functions can be reached by shortcut keys, making typing out the command unnecessarily slow.

The "of", "open", or "File.OpenFile" command, for instance, is probably equivalent to navigating to the Solution Explorer ("CTRL+Tab" and arrow around, or one of the shortcuts for Solution Explorer "CTRL+W, S", "CTRL+ALT+L", or another of your creation), then typing the name of the file you want.  The Solution Explorer will select the file as you type, press enter when you get to the right file.

Adding references can be done quickly by selecting the correct project in the solution explorer and pressing "Alt,P,R" (Just don't hit CTRL+Tab here because then VS will scour the registry for all the com components, use CTRL+SHIFT+Tab!).  Adding a new code file is similar: "Alt,P,W, 'code', ".  The menu system in Visual Studio is very well thought out. Using alt to get around it is very efficient, and beats the Command Window.

I currently use the command window (CTRL+Shift+C) to "closeall", "File.CloseAllButThis", and "open".  I had high hopes for the Command Window when I first learned of its existence.  I think I was basically looking for VIM, but don't expect too much from it, especially if you don't mind using shortcut keys for Find and other commands.

Comment: I know this is old but I saw in your post that you wanted vim for visual studio. Have you tried vsVim. I use it am liking it a lot.

Comment: @AlexanderVanAtta Not odd at all, and thank you for the recommendation. I haven't used VS and haven't developed on Microsoft systems in years, though, and now I use vim every day, all day :-)

Comment: Perhaps it opens up opportunities for automation? (Not a rhetorical question.) Though it doesn't support pasting in more than one line at a time. Perhaps an early version of [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)'s "Command Palette"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Scripting does seem like the main usecase I can imagine for it, even ten years ago when I posted the answer, but I'm not sure what capabilities it has (flow control? variable expansion? etc.). As I said, I haven't touched any Microsoft desktop software in nearly a decade.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2015, use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcut key to make the command line window appear with the current path of your project.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Doesn't Alt + Space invoke the window menu (of any window in Windows), with *"Restore"*, *"Maximize"*, *"Minimize"*, *"Close"*, etc.? What version of Windows did you try it on?