# How can I open the terminal in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I open the terminal for executing shell commands in Visual Studio (Community Edition)?

Comment: ctrl + alt + A for command window?

Comment: probably a awfully stupid question (but how else would I learn) but the Command window with ctrl + alt + a does not let me cd or urse the runserver. How do I get the equivalent to Powershell in terms of shell commands? Thank you for your answer none the less

Comment: you can use some commands in Package Manager Console like cd, dir... You can find that under View > Other Windows

Comment: VS does not have an "integrated terminal".  You could easily add one with Tools > External Tools > Add.  Command=cmd.exe, Arguments=/k, Initial Directory=$(ProjectDir).  Or Command=powershell.exe if you prefer it.

Comment: thank you @HansPassant! How would I open it then? --> Ah, i found it already! Thank you for your answer. I completly solved my problem. Its a bit offtopic, I know. But you do not now how to hide .pyc files in the file tree, right?

Comment: There's integrated terminal extension, currently in beta https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal

Comment: @HansPassant describes how to launch cmd from VS.  This will be a separate pop-up window.  If you dock it the only option is as an "Output Window", and then it is not interactive unfortunately.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

### **Visual Studio 2022/2019**

Now Visual Studio has a built-in terminal:

[image: Terminal SS]

Menu *View* → *Terminal* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>"</kbd>)

**To change the default terminal**

Menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Terminal* → *Set As Default*

[image]

---

**Before Visual Studio 2019**

From comments, the best answer [is from Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410898/open-the-terminal-in-visual-studio#comment73880766_43410898).

1. Add an external tool.

   Menu *Tools* → *External Tools* → *Add*

   Title: Terminal (or name it yourself)

   *Command* = `cmd.exe` or *Command* = `powershell.exe`

   *Arguments* = `/k`

   *Initial Directory* = `$(ProjectDir)`
2. Menu *Tools* → *Terminal* (or whatever you put in title)
3. Enjoy!

Comment: This would be a good solution, if we could enter text into the Output window.

Comment: Note that for PowerShell you need to use -NoExit instead of /k.

Comment: Do not select 'Use Output window' or it will be a read only window.

Comment: Which version exactly?

Comment: From VS 2019 now has integrated terminal in View -> Terminal (Ctrl + `) or in Tools -> Command Line. But they are slow, take few seconds to open up. The old way too add you own CMD start much faster. To add cmd via old way, **Tools -> External Tools -> Add** , and you can use & to name your _cmd.exe_ Title: &CMD which underline _C_ as shortcut key when alt is pressed. Then you can Alt + T + C which is way faster.

Comment: On my machine it is ctrl + `

Comment: All of these terminal options for VS 2019 are completely missing for me. Terminal doesn't even appear under Environment in the settings

Comment: When I open a solution in a network path I get `UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.`. `PUSHD "%~dp0"` cannot work, because this is not a batch file, what can I do?

Comment: The context menu for (almost) any folder-like object in Solution Explorer (projects, project subfolders, etc.) includes an **Open in Terminal** item. When selected, the Terminal pane opens in VS with the current directory set to whatever you clicked on.  
  
Great for exercising command-line apps and Windows services. You may need to `cd bin\debug` in the terminal pane, but if that's too much of a chore, turn on Show All Files for the project and right-click the folder with your executable straight away.

Answer (score 76):

You can have an integrated terminal inside Visual Studio using one of these extensions:

## [Whack Whack Terminal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal)

Terminal: CMD or PowerShell

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Supports: Visual Studio 2017

[image: Whack Whack Terminal]

---

## [BuiltinCmd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lkytal.BuiltinCmd)

Terminal: CMD or PowerShell

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

Supports: Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017, and 2019

[image: BuiltinCmd]

Comment: This extension opens only one terminal window. Is there a way/another extension to open multiple, like VSCode allows?

Comment: For some reason, neither extension worked for me. I was unable to enter text.

Comment: @sabdiel I noticed that you can't use the terminal when you are viewing read-only file or just no editable file is opened.

Comment: There is apparently a terminal [built into Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410898/how-can-i-open-the-terminal-in-visual-studio/52167265#52167265). Perhaps it is time for an update? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 23):

As a tricky solution, you can use *Package Manager Console* to execute [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or PowerShell commands.

Shortcut for Package Manager Console: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, + <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>

Tested on **Visual Studio 2017 Community** version.

[image]

[Also it's available now as part of **Visual Studio version 16.3 Preview 3**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/)

The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, the same as [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

Answer (score 15):

**GOOD NEWS!** Now, Visual studio has built-in terminal. In visual studio 2022 (and latest vs2019), We can open terminal from `View`>`Terminal`

[image: open terminal in vs2022]

In [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019), you can open Command/PowerShell window from menu *Tools* → *Command Line*:

[image]

If you want an integrated terminal, try
**[BuiltinCmd](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lkytal.BuiltinCmd)**:

[image]

You can also try [WhackWhackTerminal](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dos-cafe.WhackWhackTerminal) (does not support Visual Studio 2019 by this date).

Answer (score 11):

New in the most recent version of Visual Studio, there is menu *View* → *Terminal*, which will open a PowerShell instance as a Visual Studio dockable window, rather than a floating PowerShell or [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) instance from the Developer Command Prompt.

[image: Menu "View" and then "Terminal"]

Comment: Re *"the most recent version of Visual Studio"*: What version is it? *"Most recent"* quickly gets out of date.

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft just included an integrated Windows Terminal in Visual Studio version 16.3 Preview 3. Go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Preview Features*, enable the *Experimental VS Terminal* option and restart Visual Studio.

*[Say hello to the new Visual Studio terminal!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/)*

Comment: The Experimental VS Terminal seems to have been removed again with VS 16.3.3. At least I could not find it in VS versions 16.3.3--16.3.5.

Comment: Seems it will be in 16.5 -> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/842521/missing-terminal-window-in-visual-studio-2019-164.html

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019, menu *Tools* → *Command Line* → *Developer Command Prompt*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this will help, but I usually pull the command prompt up by going into "Synchronization" tab in Team Explorer and clicking on "Actions".

When the command prompt opens, it is in the directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your solution and above *"Properties"* is the option *"Open Command Line"* which gives access to the default CMD, PowerShell and developer command prompts.

Alternatively, you can use the shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> for the default (CMD), <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> for Developer (cmd), <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> for PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

To open the terminal:

- Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> keyboard shortcut with the backtick character. This command works for both Linux and macOS.
- Use the menu *View* → *Terminal* menu command.
- From the Command Palette (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.

Please find more about the integrated terminal in  *[Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)*.

Comment: This does ***not*** answer the question. The question is about [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), not [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code). "Command Palette", the provided link, and the mention of Mac and Linux (Visual Studio only runs on Windows) ***all*** indicate this answer is for Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

In case `you don't see view->terminal`, please - check your installed plugins. In my case Terminal disappeared after i installed "vsSolutionBuildEvent" plugin. I don't know why and how it is related, but "Terminal" appeared again only i uninstalled it. `CTRL+~` is also start working. MVS 2022 Community Edition.

Hope, will help someone.

Answer (score -3):

Menu *View* → *Debug console* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>). Next to the debug console is the terminal.

Answer (score -17):

For Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Alternatively from command panel **view -> Other Windows -> Command Window**

[image: Command Window menu]

Comment: Terminal is where you can run OS commands, this `Command Windows` is only for internal VS commands.

Comment: Also [discussed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410898/open-the-terminal-in-visual-studio#comment73880563_43410898).

Comment: The downvoting is correct. The "Command Window" is ***not*** a command-line window. For an elaboration, see e.g. *[What is the usefulness of the Command Window in Visual Studio (menu View → Other Windows → Command Window)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557371)*. For example, `of Class1.cs` in that window to open file `Class1.cs`. Issuing `DIR` in that window will result in ***"Command "DIR" is not valid"***.