# Can't find terminal on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, visual-studio

want to start by saying I'm completely new to programming so please bear with me.

I am trying to learn programming by building an ecommerce website with Python and Django using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZvRrldjf1Y. The first step of the tutorial is cloning the github project which I am able to do but the next step involves opening a virtual environment in Visual studio and then installing the requirements which is where I get lost. The problem is I don't know where terminal is so I can't input the commands that I need to use.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 and this is what I see after cloining the project. Terminal should be at bottom I thought but I don't see it there. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?
[visualstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RlKv.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open the terminal in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410898/open-the-terminal-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

a tool used in the Youtube link is Visual Studio Code which you can download from here https://code.visualstudio.com/download. in that, you will be able to find the terminal as a menu item on the top bar.