# What is the difference between Immediate Window and Command Window in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio

In VisualStudio the `Immediate Window` is used to debug and evaluate expressions, execute statements, print variable values, and so forth. It allows you to enter expressions to be evaluated or executed by the development language during debugging. (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx))

The `Command Window` is used to execute commands or aliases directly in the Visual Studio integrated development environment (IDE). (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c785s0kz.aspx) too)

Knowing that we can execute the Command Window commands from the Immediate Window by preceding the command by `">"`

My question is what's the difference then, why they are both their ? Are there additions in the Command Window that are not accessible or available in the Immediate Window ? Can I just keep using the Immediate Window for both purposes ? (I mean is it just sufficient and enough ?).

Comment: They provide a command line interface to respectively the IDE and the debugger.  Sure, there's plenty of overlap.  The IDE operates in two distinct modes as well, maintaining two distinct sets of window layouts.  Having the Command window in IDE mode and the Immediate window in debug mode is the "natural" way.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, can you please add it as an answer, thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command vs. Immediate Window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000665/command-vs-immediate-window-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Command Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557371/visual-studio-command-window)

Comment: Also, if someone wants to run trivial windows shell commands while staying within Visual Studio - [Using the command line from within Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9827567/465053)